# How can I write all the answer in the function zip or in Json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a response from the site. I want to write it in Json or Zip. But I do not know how to do it. What should I write ?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
from pprint import pprint


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text




def get_data(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('table', {'style':'padding-top:10px;'})

    for rows in trs.find_all('tr'):
        pairs = rows.find_all('a')
        for pair in pairs:
            for elem in pair:
                print(elem)




def main():
    groups = {
        'T-691': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=26',
        'Т-717': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=62'
    }
    group = input()
    url = 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id={}'.format(groups[group])
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like this answer to be so

('Item': 'Name', 'Group Number': 'Name'), etc.

Comment: Please post your question in English or at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ .

Comment: I corrected please look

Comment: So, if I am looking at БухУчет   Яскевич И.В.  Т-691  504 what is item:name, group:number etc?

Comment: Subject:БухУчет  , teacher:Яскевия И.В, group:Т-691 , cabinet:504

Comment: how does that match with your  _('Item': 'Name', 'Group Number': 'Name')_  ? I think show expected output using a a couple of lines with real examples.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to create a list of dictionaries in the format you want. I am assuming each 4 values per cell needs to be in it's own entry, as such the following first builds a list of all of the entries. This is returned to the caller and Python's `json.dump()` is used to write the list to `output.json`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint


fields = ['Item', 'Group number', 'Field 3', 'Field 4']
record = itemgetter(0, 1, 3, 4)    # Skip the blank 2nd entry


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_data(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('table', {'style':'padding-top:10px;'})

    rows = []

    for tr in trs.find_all('tr'):
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            a_tags = td.find_all('a')

            if a_tags:
                row = {field : value.get_text(strip=True) for field, value in zip(fields, record(a_tags))}
                rows.append(row)

    return rows


def main():
    groups = {
        'T-691': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=26',
        'Т-717': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=62'
    }

    group = input()
    url = 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id={}'.format(groups[group])
    rows = get_data(get_html(url))

    with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
        json.dump(rows, f_output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Giving you `output.json` starting:

```json
[
    {
        "Item": "ТестОтладкаПО",
        "Group number": "Якимович К",
        "Field 3": "Т-691",
        "Field 4": "408"
    },
    {
        "Item": "МатемМоделир",
        "Group number": "Клименко Д.Ф.",
        "Field 3": "Т-691",
        "Field 4": "429"
    }
]
```

You will need to assign the correct field names.